# Google spreadsheet ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to get the lowest product price from this site into a Google spreadsheet.
https://multimedialne-centra.heureka.sk/homatics-dongle-q/

I don't know how to enter the condition but it should be something like this:
From the first `<a>` with the parameter `data-gtm-position-type="free"` take the value from `SPAN` with `class="c-offer-v3__price"`

But how to define it in a spreadsheet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use importxml for this. If just a lowest price is o.k. for you then you can write:

```
=min(importxml("https://multimedialne-centra.heureka.sk/homatics-dongle-q/";"//span[@class="c-offer-v3__price u-bold u-delta"]"))
```

It takes all the values from corresponding xpath and extracts lowest of them.

Comment: I'd use SORT + INDEX instead of MIN since it takes numeric values, e.g. `=INDEX(SORT(IMPORTXML("https://multimedialne-centra.heureka.sk/homatics-dongle-q/","//span[@class='c-offer-v3__price u-bold u-delta']")), 1, 1)`